# Help with formula

Tags: google-sheets

this is what I am trying to do and need a formula for column C on the tee sheet

[image]

Comment: Best is to share the doc with us.......

Comment: And please include more information in your question's text and title, so that it will be searchable for others having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The formula in Column C of the Tee sheet would be something like:

```
= D3 - VLOOKUP(B3,Scoring!$A$2:Scoring!$AB$999,28,FALSE)
```

Drawback of this is that it only works within the same document, across different sheets. I don't think the VLOOKUP can work across documents.